# Powershell If statement to get OS Architecture from remote computers

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to write a powershell script that reaches out to a group of computers and according to the OS Architecture 32 or 64 bit runs the install. But I cannot get it to work.

```
$Computers =Get-Content -Path.\vms.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    If ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture).osarchitecture -like "64*")
    {
    Start-Process D:\setup64.exe 
    }
    Else
    {
    Start-Process D:\setup.exe
    }
}
```

I get two errors from Powershell one is that it cannot find the file and the other is that it doesn't recognize the Else

Comment: #1. Opening bracket should be on the same line with `if` condition. #2. `| select osarchitecture` is redundand. #3. Does file exist on remote machine ?

Comment: Which PowerShell version? What are the exact error message? Note that `Get-WmiObject` depleted in PowerShell Core.

Comment: The file exist on the same directory and it has the names of the computers in it. I'm using PowerShell 2.0

Comment: Are you sure all computers in the list have the setup files `D:\setup64.exe` and `D:\setup.exe` available on **their** local disks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting? That the files don't exist? Is the .exe not running?

Based off what you posted above, piping a select to your gwmi is redundant like @filimonic pointed out. You are also missing the closing statement for your script block `}`.

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path .\vms.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers){ 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    If ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).osarchitecture -like "64*"){
        Start-Process D:\setup64.exe}Else{
        Start-Process D:\setup.exe
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Give this a shot. . .

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path .\vms.txt

foreach ($Computer in $Computers){ 
$OS = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty osarchitecture 
    if($OS -like "64*"){

Invoke-WmiMethod -path win32_process -ComputerName $Computer -name create -argumentlist "CMD /C `"D:\setup.exe`""}else{
Invoke-WmiMethod -path win32_process -ComputerName $Computer -name create -argumentlist "CMD /C `"D:\setup.exe`""
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Theoretically, this should work as well. . .

```
$sessions =  New-PSSession -ComputerName (Get-Content -Path .\vms.txt)
    foreach ($Computer in $sessions){ 

Invoke-Command -Session $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    If ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).osarchitecture -like "64*"){
        Start-Process D:\setup64.exe}Else{
        Start-Process D:\setup.exe
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks fixing the closing statement worked but I can't still run any program on the remote machine I changed the Start-Process to Start-Process to:                                            
    Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe         but still doesn't work

Comment: Powershell remoting is done using a netlogon with the credentials of the session your running the code with. You wont see whatever you're running if someone else is logged in because its running it on your account.

Comment: What you can see is the process of all users in TaskManager or, you can run a `Get-Process` against the machine before, and after you run the code to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks Abraham, I'm aware of this  but notepad doesn't show in the processes list. I don't have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I don't get any errors.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Try this against a single machine and see if the notepad still doesn't show: `Invoke-WmiMethod -path win32_process -ComputerName "CompName" -name create -argumentlist notepad.exe`.

Comment: Ok, Just tried that I get  a error at Invoke-WmiMethod it says character 17 which is right after the last character of Invoke-WmiMethod. This is the exact message "Invoke-WmiMethod : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:1 char:17
+ Invoke-WmiMethod <<<<  -path win32_process -ComputerName Win72 -name create -argumentlist notepad.exe
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMethod" rpc and winrm available

Comment: Did you try the edits in my post? Also, is your computer named win72?

Comment: Abraham Thanks, I tried your edits  the one with the "Invoke-WmiMethod" worked the other one didn't I copied and pasted the code from your post to make sure I didn't mistyped something on the one other one I got rpc server is unavailable which doesn't make sense to me since the edit with  "Invoke-WmiMethod" worked again Thanks.